# Breeze: SaveChanges client does not call SaveChanges server - still .succeed after execution

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, breeze

I'm not looking for a code-based solution but I rather have an explanation to the problem I ran into.

For the application I'm developing, the back-end is my territory and my colleague is the responsible for the front-end. My colleague has left without any documentation that could help me out resolving this, therefore I'm asking StackOverflow for a little help.

The application is running and everything works, except for one bit. At one point in the application, the client side breeze calls the SaveChanges method, which (everywhere else in the application) triggers the SaveChanges method on the server. In this specific instance, the SaveChanges method returns to the .succeed and delivers the (custom?) notification in the console that the changes are saved. **However**, the server does not receive any calls and in the network log I don't see any calls. Can you point me in a direction what may causes this, so I can understand this for future problems? Thanks in advance.

```
function saveChanges(request, options, onSuccess, onFailure) {
        if (options) {
            if (!options.hasFlight) {
                _.forEach(request.FlightRequests, function (val) {
                    removeFlight(request, val, true);
                });
            }

            if (!options.hasFerry) {
                _.forEach(request.FerryRequests, function (val) {
                    removeFerry(request, val);
                });
            }

            if (!options.hasEurotunnel) {
                _.forEach(request.EuroTunnelRequests, function (val) {
                    removeEurotunnel(request, val);
                });
            }

            if (!options.hasRentalCar) {
                _.forEach(request.RentalCarRequests, function (val) {
                    removeRentalcar(request, val);
                });
            }

            if (!options.hasTaxi) {
                _.forEach(request.TaxiRequests, function (val) {
                    removeTaxi(request, val);
                });
            }

            if (!options.hasAccommodation) {
                _.forEach(request.Accommodations, function (val) {
                    removeAccommodation(request, val);
                });
            }
        }

        return manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .catch(saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(result) {
            console.log('Successfully saved all changes');
            onSuccess(result);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var reason = error.message;
            var detail = error.detail;

            if (error.entityErrors) {
                handleSaveValidationError(error);
            } else if (detail && detail.ExceptionType &&
                detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
                reason = 'Another user, perhaps the server itself, may have deleted '
                + 'the request you are currenty working on. Please try saving again, '
                + 'or reload this web page.';
            } else {
                reason = 'Failed to save changes: ' + reason + ' You may have to reload this web page.';
            }
            console.log(detail.ExceptionType);
            console.log(error, reason);

            onFailure(error, reason);
        }
    }
```

This code runs fine for all the saves, except for this single point in the application.

Answer (score 0):

if you check `manager.hasChanges()` prior to the `manager.saveChanges()` line, does it return false?  If it does, no request will go to the server (breezejs code [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/files/.._.._src_a50_entityManager.js.html#l828)).

[Here's an example](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/save-changes) of using the hasChanges method in conjunction with saveChanges.

Comment: Alternatively, you can confirm that nothing was actually saved by examining the `saveResult` value returned in the success callback. It's easy to detect that the call was not made. Among other things, `saveResult.entities.length` will be zero.

Comment: It definitely has changes however .hasChanges() tells me there are no changes... This is very confusing